# How to select certain rows from dataset?

Tags: r

The dataset is Netflix stock price with 8 variables (8 columns)
So I am picking the 3 columns I need by using

```
select("date", "open", "close")

  date        open close
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2011-01-03  25    25.5
 2 2011-01-04  25.9  25.9
 3 2011-01-05  25.9  25.7
 4 2011-01-06  25.2  25.4
 5 2011-01-07  25.5  25.6
 6 2011-01-10  25.7  26.8
 7 2011-01-11  27.1  26.7
 8 2011-01-12  26.9  27.0
 9 2011-01-13  26.9  27.4
10 2011-01-14  27.3  27.4
```

1. I wanna pick only the rows where the opening price is higher
   than previous days closing price
2. And also, the closing price has to be higher than the opening for that same day
   So for this dataset only 3 rows are qualifying: Jan 7th, Jan 10th and Jan 12th.
   If somebody could help me to understand how to code this, I would really appreciate.

Comment: It would be helpful to allow others to reproduce your data easily. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/6607497 for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
result <- df %>% filter(open > lag(close), close > open)
result
#        date open close
#1 2011-01-07 25.5  25.6
#2 2011-01-10 25.7  26.8
#3 2011-01-12 26.9  27.0
```

And the same in base R and `data.table` :

```
#Base R
subset(df, open > c(NA, close[-nrow(df)]) & close > open)

#data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[open > shift(close) & close > open]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(14977, 14978, 14979, 14980, 
14981, 14984, 14985, 14986, 14987, 14988), class = "Date"), open = c(25, 
25.9, 25.9, 25.2, 25.5, 25.7, 27.1, 26.9, 26.9, 27.3), close = c(25.5, 
25.9, 25.7, 25.4, 25.6, 26.8, 26.7, 27, 27.4, 27.4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I used dplyr and it works! You the man, thanks a lot!!!